# If I can only use javascript, how can I filter list by date?

Tags: javascript

I have this list structure:

```
<ul class="pol list">                       
<li>
    <div class="tekst">
        <h2><span class="name"></span></h2>
        <p class="description"></p>                 
        <div class="commentsBar1">
            <div class="commentsBarL1">
                    <h5>
                    <strong class="category">
                    <span style="display:none;"></span>
                    <span class="d">27.12.2011</span>
                    </strong>    
                </h5>
                <h5><strong></strong></h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="tekst">
        <h2><span class="name"></span></h2>
        <p class="description"></p>                 
        <div class="commentsBar1">
            <div class="commentsBarL1">
                <h5>
                    <strong class="category">
                    <span style="display:none;"></span>
                    <span class="d">03.03.2012</span>
                    </strong>    
                </h5>
                <h5><strong></strong></h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

I need  js that will hide all list tags which contain a date outside of a certain range. The date range is given by user and both start and end dates are given in same way as dates in the list (dd.mm.yyyy).

```
<input id="Date1" name="Date1"> 
<input id="Date2" name="Date2">
```

I have this date comparison code:

```
var dControl = document.getElementsByClassName("d");
var d1Control = document.getElementById("Date1");
var d2Control = document.getElementById("Date2");

var arrD = dControl.value.split(".");
var dd0 = new Date(arrStartDate[2], arrStartDate[1], arrStartDate[0]);
var arrD1 = d1Control.value.split(".");
var dd1 = new Date(arrStartDate[2], arrStartDate[1], arrStartDate[0]);
var arrD2 = d2Control.value.split(".");
var dd2 = new Date(arrStartDate[2], arrStartDate[1], arrStartDate[0]);

    if((dd0 <= dd2 && dd0 >= dd1)) {
            return true;
    }
    return false;
```

And one more thing... The number of list elements varies from page to page so I also need to get some idea about the list size, but that I assume is easy to do with "length".

Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Comment: There are a number of ways this can be accomplished. Do you already have the dom parsing and date compare code written?

Comment: **Do you have anything written?**

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to post my js... 
The thing is that I'm a student, with no previous experience with js and with no idea how to get this thing working.
And unfortunately I'm not allowed to use anything but js.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write javascript to build the dom based on the dates you have. I suggest using a templating framework such as mustache or handlebars to keep your code tidy.

Answer (score 0):

just run through the elements with class "d" and check if they meet your date criteria if not then set that li to display "none". you will have to find the li in the DOM node tree which appears to be 8 levels higher that your date.